# CSS: Why does fixed element NOT start at the top of the page in this example?

Tags: css, html, stylesheet

In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/trusktr/CyaJ8/), why doesn't the fixed #header (the at the top) start at the top of the page, but in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/trusktr/EsHTK/) it does?

The only difference is that i changed the "margin" of #content to "padding" instead (repsectively).

So why does this tiny change have a huge impact? How do I put the fixed #header at the top of the page while still using "margin" for the #content?

Comment: including top: 0 might do the trick...

Comment: @Kasturi it does. Not sure why this is the case though or else I would have added an answer for OP lol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because of [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins).

> If the top and bottom margins of a box
>   are adjoining, then it is possible for
>   margins to collapse through it. In
>   this case, the position of the element
>   depends on its relationship with the
>   other elements whose margins are being
>   collapsed.

In this case, the `margin` can push down the `#header` (that has `position: fixed`) unless you give it a `top` value other than the default of `auto`.

A way to fix this is to add `overflow: hidden` to `#wrapper`: http://jsfiddle.net/CyaJ8/6/

This works because:

> Margins of elements that establish new
>   block formatting contexts (such as
>   floats and **elements with 'overflow'
>   other than 'visible'**) do not collapse
>   with their in-flow children.

Comment: I understand collapsing margins as described here:http://ghz.me/6l But why does this push the fixed element down? I don't quite understand. I understand that the biggest vertical margin between two elements at the same child-level that are adjoined will be honored. How does that affect the fixed element?

Comment: @trusktr: I'll admit, I can't quite fathom the excruciating technical detail from the W3 specs to precisely answer what's going on. The best I can do is say that it's definitely related to collapsing margins.

Comment: yeah, it's so complicated. it's almost like an unwritten rule. It's easy enough to use `top` though.

Answer (score 2):

Adding

```
#header { top: 0; }
```

should solve the problem.